# Java API for XML Schema manipulation

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd

I am familiar with JAXB, JAXP and DOM. I know JAXB provides java2xml and xml2java generation(and validation against XML Schema(XSD)). What I want is convenient way to produce XML schema programmatically from scratch. I do not want to produce XSD from java classes. I want to have an object representing the schema itself. For example:

```
XMLSchemaFactory factory = XMLSchemaFactory.newInstance();
XMLSchema schema = factory.newSchema();
schema.setTargetNameSpace("http://www.example.com");
...
schema.addComplexType(complexTypeElement);
...
schema.addElement(name, type);
...
schema.export(new File("mySchema.xsd"));
```

I know XML schema is itself XML, so I can use Document, Element, Node and other classes/interfaces from [org.w3c.dom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html), but I wonder is there something more convenient ?
Why I want this - I have some IDL, which I have to translate to WSDL. I have lexer/parser for the IDL and I have convenient representation of it as java objects. Now I want to produce the WSDL using this objects => a lot of XML schemas have to be generated !

Comment: Why not use WSDL4J API? http://wsdl4j.sourceforge.net/downloads/JSR110_proposed_final_draft.pdf

Comment: This is useful and i will pay attention but it is designed to work with WSDL specific elements.
"4. Out of Scope:
JWSDL does not provide support for querying/manipulating XML Schema. "
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From my point use WSDL4J it would be pretty easier for your xml manipulations.

Refer this pdf for more details.

http://wsdl4j.sourceforge.net/downloads/JSR110_proposed_final_draft.pdf